# Android Studio - Retrieve store distance from phone

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to evaluate the distance between a user and a nearby location (such as Walmart or any other store). I have look over Google places, but I am having a hard time to retrieve store location nearby the phone. I am not going to be displaying a map or anything of that kind, I just want to evaluate distance. If anyone could recommend me a guide or a tutorial on how to retrieve the most nearby store location and evaluate the distance between the phone and store.

Comment: I would recommend google so go and search for determining distance between to geolocations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can get places near by your location using Google Place API and for use of Place Api see this [blog](http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-google-places-api.html)

2) And for distance calculation use this:

```
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
  var a = 
    Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * 
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
    ; 
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI/180)
}
```

Comment: But this only evaluate distance directly, I want to evaluate the route distance between the user and the store

Comment: What do you mean by route distance ?? If you mean to find the distance as user moves to the store then this should work.

Comment: You can call this method every time the user moves to the store and get the current distance between user and store.

Comment: with route distance I mean the street route distance, since the drive to the store isn't a straight line. I am not sure if I understood your code correctly, but would it consider roads when calculating distance?

Comment: Ofcourse it will. The method gives the distance in Kilometers depending on the original lat lng .... So it will give the distance accurately depending on route as well.

Comment: I apologies it seems I understood the code wrong, however I am having hard issue to figure out how to retrieve a certain store location nearby (Like Walmart). I have looked over the blog and google places blog but still unable to understand how I can search for the store mind helping me out with a reference to a code or something similar thanks

Comment: You can refer to this link: https://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/  .It is old but you will get a clear idea of how to use the Places api.

Comment: Of course, just one last question I was able to retrieve the store location using Google Place url request [HERE](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) and was given proper json with the information I need to get the longitude and latitude. I know this is annoying but I am a beginner and would like to ask how would I go by adding this into android studio since I never done web request. Thanks

Comment: You can use https://github.com/google/volley or http://square.github.io/retrofit/ for this purpose both are amazing for web requests.

Comment: Thanks but to be honest this seems to be too complicated for me to understand, I will look around for an easier guide. However, I couldn't thank you enough for your help